# Alignment in enumerate with self-defined labels

Tags: enumerate, itemize, alignment

I have the following enumerate-environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textsc{Step \arabic*:}]
\item first
\item second
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item first
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to have the "S" from "Step" above the dot from itemize? Or centered above the dot?

Comment: Oups sorry! Edited...

Comment: Don't know how to create a figure but so far the numbers 1,2,3 from "Step" are in a line with the dot from the itemize environment. But I want the three "S" from the words "Step" to be in a line with the dots. Mainly because the word Step is in the margin.

Comment: That results from the default right-alignment of the labels at the left margin of the list. As your labels of the list are longer than the default, it makes them flow into the text left margin, as you can see if you load the `showframe` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You enumerate labels go into the margin. Use the `wide` option: this makes the labels left-aligned, instead of right-aligned at the margin:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textsc{Step \arabic*:}, wide]
\item first
\item second
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item first
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you Bernard. I have seen only two "S". Basically the user wanted the point below step. I had not understood that absolutely.